# Вконтакте: ошибка "Code is invalid or expired"

Tags: oauth, ajax, javascript, вконтакте

При получении access_token истекает время действия кода, при чем когда делаешь запрос через ajax. Если просто перейти по урлу, то я вижу этот токен. В чем проблема, учитывая то, что этот код, как написано в доках живет час?

Comment: Вы для чего получаете `access_token`?

Answer (score 0):

[Аутентификация через ВКонтакте](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1659) почитайте, есть вероятность что что-то написано не правильно у вас в коде =)

Comment: Не знаю, что и сказать, потому что с одной стороны это решение для сервер-сайд. А с другой стороны для меня работает такой вариант: 

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=XXX&scope=friends&redirect_uri=XXX&display=wap&response_type=token

Т.е. я миную получение code